# how to use awk to parse a file with multiple record types

Tags: awk, gawk

Want to process an input file with `awk`.  There are multiple record types denoted by one of the fields in the incoming records.  When the record type contains a specific value, I need to process N number of additional records following the current one that contain data specific to this type of record.

Is this doable with `awk`?

Here is a sample of the format of the incoming file:

```
 1 [001:01.0] [ 2] IOCTL 048477589
...
...
28 [002:02.0] [ 2] TX(56)
        81480d0d 0a524141 435a5955 5705243  .H...RAACZYW RC
        43544848 41303033 32203034 3032325  CTHHA0032 04025
        332d4343 43432d2d 52435554 4848412  3-CCCC--RCETHHA
```

So, basically, when a TX type record is found, read the next N records processing
the data, reading in the hex and ASCII equivalent.

??

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're aiming to do, but here's something that may serve as a start. Replace the `print` statements with more substantial processing, as needed.

```
awk '
/^[ 0-9][0-9] / {
    # This is a record header line. Check if it is a TX.
    inTx = ($0 ~ / TX\([0-9]*\)$/);
    if (inTx) {
        print "Start of TX record.";
        next; # Avoid printing the header line below.
    }
}
inTx { print "TX:", $0; }
' file.txt
```

Here's a somewhat beefier example file, to make it a little more clear what the script does:

```
 1 [001:01.0] [ 2] IOCTL 048477589
...
...
28 [002:02.0] [ 2] TX(56)
        81480d0d 0a524141 435a5955 5705243  .H...RAACZYW RC
        43544848 41303033 32203034 3032325  CTHHA0032 04025
        332d4343 43432d2d 52435554 4848412  3-CCCC--RCETHHA
 1 [001:01.0] [ 2] IOCTL 048477589
 2 [dsfsdsdf] [ 2] BLORT
29 [002:02.0] [ 2] TX(77)
        abbababa 0a524141 435a5955 5705243  STUFFSTUFFSTUFF
        43544848 bbbbbbbb 32203034 d0d0d0d  CTHULUCTHULUCTH
        332d4343 43432d2d cccccccc 4848412  BLORTZORCHFNORD
 1 [001:01.0] [ 2] IOCTL 048477589
 2 [dsfsdsdf] [ 2] BLORT
```

Transcript of running the script:

```
Start of TX record.
TX:         81480d0d 0a524141 435a5955 5705243  .H...RAACZYW RC
TX:         43544848 41303033 32203034 3032325  CTHHA0032 04025
TX:         332d4343 43432d2d 52435554 4848412  3-CCCC--RCETHHA
Start of TX record.
TX:         abbababa 0a524141 435a5955 5705243  STUFFSTUFFSTUFF
TX:         43544848 bbbbbbbb 32203034 d0d0d0d  CTHULUCTHULUCTH
TX:         332d4343 43432d2d cccccccc 4848412  BLORTZORCHFNORD
```

Comment: thx, I  got it working.  Basically, I created a state machine decoding on the TX/RX type fields.  They spit out N number of additional records which can be in baudot format where only the hex values are included.  The objective is to translate those hex values into their ascii format.  I used a lookup table to accomplish it.